# Unity Android Project Settings.gradle file

Tags: unity, android

I am trying to debug Android project after building it with Unity Editor

The project i want to include is an External Project.

the usual way is Adding to settings.gradle

```
:include (':common')
:project (':common') as File(...)
```

and build.gradle

```
compile project(':common')
```

1.Its doesn't seems to work since i have no idea (if possible) place the settings.gradle for usage.
Any1 manage to fix it?

2.maybe there is another way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve and why it's not working...

Comment: My Unity is based on Android external Project.. i want to "attach" external project so i can debug the libs i am using..

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and improve it to make it a bit clearer of what you want to ultimately achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Fix..
Posting Answer for Future Reference.

Export Project using Unity.
include the exported project to your external Project in the Settings.gradle

```
include ':project'
project (":project").projectDir = new File('project path')
```

Build external project run and you can Debug.